# DBの具象テーブル継承時に、具象先が単一であることを保証する仕組み

Tags: database

例えば、`Student`クラスと`Teacher`クラスが、`User`クラスを継承しているとします。
それをDBテーブルで表現すると、以下のようになるかと思います。（具象テーブル継承）

`user`テーブル

- id （※主キー）
- name（氏名）
- ...

`student`テーブル

- user_id（※外部キー）
- student_no（学籍番号）
- class_room（所属クラス）
- ...

`teacher`テーブル

- user_id（※外部キー）
- office_room（職員用の居室）
- ...

このとき、`user`の具象先（`student`か`teacher`）が単一であることを保証する仕組みは、存在しますでしょうか？
ある`user`レコードに対して、`student`と`teacher`の両方にレコードが存在できてしまう場合を懸念しています。

Comment: 「単一テーブル継承」で調べると[この辺](https://qiita.com/kidach1/items/789c2e7aebbcfbd2583e)が出てきますけど、クラス設計を大きく変更することは可能ですか？

Comment: どういう状況を想定しているでしょうか？通常はORMapperが保証する話(抽象クラステーブル、具象クラステーブルはまとめて操作するので懸念してるような事象は発生しない)だと思います。[こちらの回答にあるような対応](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/74355/2808)は、継承クラスが増えるたびに新しいカラムが必要になるのであまり一般的に採用できる対応であるとは思えません。

Comment: @keitaro_so わかりづらくてすみません、各テーブルにカラムを追記します。`student`テーブルと`teacher`テーブルでは異なるカラムを持たせる想定ですので、単一テーブル継承は今回は適用できないと考えています。

Comment: @DEWAKazuyuki-出羽和之 アプリ側でも保証はできますが、データ構造上の制約はDB側でできるべきでは、と考えました（外部キー制約等のように）。ただ、確かに継承クラスが増えるたびに親クラスにカラムを増やすのはよくないかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご質問のクラステーブル継承を使った場合でも、CHECK制約を使って継承先を一意に特定することができます。

1. `Student`テーブルと`teacher`テーブルにそれぞれ`STUDENT_ID`と`TEACHER_ID`を主キー(PK)として設定します。
2. それを`user`テーブルの該当カラムに外部キー(FK)として追加します。
3. 最後に`user`テーブルのCHECK制約として下記を設定します。
   (下記はOracleの構文例です)

```
CONSTRAINT CHK_TYPE CHECK (case when STUDENT_ID is NULL then 0 else 1 end + case when TEACHER_ID is NULL then 0 else 1 end = 1)
```

このCHECK制約は1つ目のcase文で`STUDENT_ID`の有無を、2つ目のcase文で`TEACHER_ID`の有無をフラグ化して、どちらか片方しかない場合のみチェックが通るようにしています。

このテーブル設計により、`Student`テーブルの`STUDENT_ID`は一意であり、`teacher`テーブルの`TEACHER_ID`も一意であることが保証されます。
`user`テーブルの上記IDを`Student`テーブルと`teacher`テーブルに外部結合する設計で、「ある`user`レコードに対して、`student`と`teacher`の両方にレコードが存在できてしまう場合」はなくなります。

ただしこの状態では「`user`テーブルに同一の`Student`レコード(または`teacher`レコード)が重複できてしまう場合」が防げませんので、必要に応じて重複チェックなどを追加してください。

参考: [データベースでクラス継承を表現する](http://cs.hatenablog.jp/entry/2013/07/13/010318)

---

Oracleで検証に使ったコード:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
    STUDENT_ID                     NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENT PRIMARY KEY (STUDENT_ID) USING INDEX
);
/
CREATE TABLE TEACHER
(
    TEACHER_ID                     NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TEACHER PRIMARY KEY (TEACHER_ID) USING INDEX
);
/
CREATE TABLE USER
(
    USER_ID                        NUMBER,
    STUDENT_ID                     NUMBER,
    TEACHER_ID                     NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_TYPE CHECK (case when STUDENT_ID is NULL then 0 else 1 end +  case when TEACHER_ID is NULL then 0 else 1 end = 1),
    CONSTRAINT FK_STUDENT FOREIGN KEY (STUDENT_ID) REFERENCES STUDENT (STUDENT_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_TEACHER FOREIGN KEY (TEACHER_ID) REFERENCES TEACHER (TEACHER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

---

@keitaro_so さんのご賢察の通り、私の回答は継承元の制約がありませんので参考にされる方はご留意願います。

各種テーブルで相互に外部キーを貼ることによって、片方にしか存在しないキーができないように監視することができます。
ただしこの仕組みは遅延制約(`DEFERRABLE`)やトリガなどを使って一瞬だけ外部キー制約を回避しないと実現できません。
(新規レコードを追加する時、`teacher`テーブルに入れようとしても`user`テーブルがないので制約違反になり、`user`テーブルに入れようとしてもまた制約違反になります)

CHECK制約はSqliteを含めて大抵のRDBで実装されていますが、遅延制約はPostgresqlとOracleくらいしか見つからなかったので回答に含めませんでした。
参考: http://cs.hatenablog.jp/entry/2013/07/12/235046

Comment: CHECK制約により仕組みを実現できるとのこと、大変勉強になりました。全く知らなかったので本当にありがたいです。

Comment: この場合って逆に継承元の制約が外れてしまいませんか？teacherだけでデータが作れてしまいます。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。関連する内容を後半に追記しました。